# C# performance using array index

Tags: c#, arrays, performance

I have an array and I want to use on single value multiple times in the same method.

```
int[] array = new array[] {1, 2, 3};
```

Now I'm asking you if its a big performance issue if I use the array and an index to get the value...

```
int x = array[1] * 2;
int y = array[1] * 3;
int z = array[1] * 4;
```

or is it better to create a local variable?

```
int value = array[1];
int x = value * 2;
int y = value * 3;
int z = value * 4;
```

I know it easier to read with a local variable, but it just interested me if it makes any performace differences. ;-)

Comment: I would choose second approach not only for performance, but for avoiding duplication.

Comment: Micro-optimizations are evil

Comment: Even if you did want to optimize this, why not make a small program to test it over many, many iterations (just like Konrad did in his answer)?

Comment: @Steve Keep in mind that benchmarking is hard, much, much more so for microoptimizations.  It's *super* easy to end up with very  misleading results that end up only indicating performance differences in the benchmarking code, rather than of the code being tested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although I agree that such **micro-optimizations are evil** and unnecessary, and **readability might be more important**, it was quite a fun to make a dummy benchmark for two methods:

```
private static int TestWithIndex(int[] array)
{
    int x = array[1] * 2;
    int y = array[1] * 3;
    int z = array[1] * 4;
    return x + y + z;
}

private static int TestWithTemp(int[] array)
{
    int value = array[1];
    int x = value * 2;
    int y = value * 3;
    int z = value * 4;
    return x + y + z;
}
```

calling them `int.MaxValue` times in `Release` mode produces:

- 12032 ms - for `TestWithIndex`
- 10525 ms - for `TestWithTemp`

And then let's look at the IL generated (Release mode, Optimizations enabled):

> TestWithIndex

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    int32 TestWithIndex (
        int32[] 'array'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2564
    // Code size 29 (0x1d)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 x,
        [1] int32 y,
        [2] int32 z,
        [3] int32 CS$1$0000
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0003: ldelem.i4
    IL_0004: ldc.i4.2
    IL_0005: mul
    IL_0006: stloc.0
    IL_0007: ldarg.0
    IL_0008: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0009: ldelem.i4
    IL_000a: ldc.i4.3
    IL_000b: mul
    IL_000c: stloc.1
    IL_000d: ldarg.0
    IL_000e: ldc.i4.1
    IL_000f: ldelem.i4
    IL_0010: ldc.i4.4
    IL_0011: mul
    IL_0012: stloc.2
    IL_0013: ldloc.0
    IL_0014: ldloc.1
    IL_0015: add
    IL_0016: ldloc.2
    IL_0017: add
    IL_0018: stloc.3
    IL_0019: br.s IL_001b

    IL_001b: ldloc.3
    IL_001c: ret
} // end of method Program::TestWithIndex
```

Here we see three `ldelem.i4`.

> TestWithTemp

```
.method private hidebysig static 
    int32 TestWithTemp (
        int32[] 'array'
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2590
    // Code size 29 (0x1d)
    .maxstack 2
    .locals init (
        [0] int32 'value',
        [1] int32 x,
        [2] int32 y,
        [3] int32 z,
        [4] int32 CS$1$0000
    )

    IL_0000: nop
    IL_0001: ldarg.0
    IL_0002: ldc.i4.1
    IL_0003: ldelem.i4
    IL_0004: stloc.0
    IL_0005: ldloc.0
    IL_0006: ldc.i4.2
    IL_0007: mul
    IL_0008: stloc.1
    IL_0009: ldloc.0
    IL_000a: ldc.i4.3
    IL_000b: mul
    IL_000c: stloc.2
    IL_000d: ldloc.0
    IL_000e: ldc.i4.4
    IL_000f: mul
    IL_0010: stloc.3
    IL_0011: ldloc.1
    IL_0012: ldloc.2
    IL_0013: add
    IL_0014: ldloc.3
    IL_0015: add
    IL_0016: stloc.s CS$1$0000
    IL_0018: br.s IL_001a

    IL_001a: ldloc.s CS$1$0000
    IL_001c: ret
} // end of method Program::TestWithTemp
```

Here only one `ldelem.i4` of course.

Comment: Thank you for you the quick answer! I supposed it wouldn't have a big effect, but it just interested me. :-)

Answer (score 2):

No, there would be no performance difference. For this to work:

```
int x = array[1] * 2;
```

the value at `array[1]` is going to have to be moved into a memory location anyway when the IL is generated. The remaining operations will then be optimized away by the compiler (i.e. it's not going to retrieve the value more than once).

---

Alright, to settle the argument I decided to dump each, here is the first:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0002:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0007:  dup
  IL_0008:  ldtoken    field valuetype '<PrivateImplementationDetails>{79A4FD92-FA37-4EB9-8056-B52A57262FBB}'/'__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=12' '<PrivateImplementationDetails>{79A4FD92-FA37-4EB9-8056-B52A57262FBB}'::'$$method0x6000001-1'
  IL_000d:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::InitializeArray(class [mscorlib]System.Array,
                                                                                                      valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeFieldHandle)
  IL_0012:  stloc.0
  IL_0013:  ldloc.0
  IL_0014:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0015:  ldelem.i4
  IL_0016:  stloc.1
  IL_0017:  ldloc.1
  IL_0018:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0019:  mul
  IL_001a:  stloc.2
  IL_001b:  ldloc.1
  IL_001c:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_001d:  mul
  IL_001e:  stloc.3
  IL_001f:  ldloc.1
  IL_0020:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_0021:  mul
  IL_0022:  stloc.s    z
  IL_0024:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

and here is the second:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  Main(string[] args) cil managed
{
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_0002:  newarr     [mscorlib]System.Int32
  IL_0007:  dup
  IL_0008:  ldtoken    field valuetype '<PrivateImplementationDetails>{79A4FD92-FA37-4EB9-8056-B52A57262FBB}'/'__StaticArrayInitTypeSize=12' '<PrivateImplementationDetails>{79A4FD92-FA37-4EB9-8056-B52A57262FBB}'::'$$method0x6000001-1'
  IL_000d:  call       void [mscorlib]System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers::InitializeArray(class [mscorlib]System.Array,
                                                                                                      valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeFieldHandle)
  IL_0012:  stloc.0
  IL_0013:  ldloc.0
  IL_0014:  ldc.i4.1
  IL_0015:  ldelem.i4
  IL_0016:  stloc.1
  IL_0017:  ldloc.1
  IL_0018:  ldc.i4.2
  IL_0019:  mul
  IL_001a:  stloc.2
  IL_001b:  ldloc.1
  IL_001c:  ldc.i4.3
  IL_001d:  mul
  IL_001e:  stloc.3
  IL_001f:  ldloc.1
  IL_0020:  ldc.i4.4
  IL_0021:  mul
  IL_0022:  stloc.s    z
  IL_0024:  ret
} // end of method Program::Main
```

They are exactly the same--as I stated.

Comment: `(i.e. it's not going to retrieve the value more than once)` How do you know that?  It doesn't know that the array value isn't going to be changed while it is executing, so it's going to need to access it again.

Comment: @Servy, with those three lines in a row it certainly knows the array value can't change--it's not being set.

Comment: another thread could be changing them.  That also means you're assuming the compiler is doing an analysis to try to determine if that particular value is being set between accesses.  That's a *very* non trivial thing to do.  What if another method is called, outside of the current scope, what if an event is fired that might have a handler that mutates the array, etc.  Too many possibilities to realistically check for.

Comment: @user2864740 So you think that the compiler is going to do a check to see if there is some form of synchronization/memory barrier and only perform the lookup if one is there?  Keep in mind it may not be explicitly in the current scope, but could be buried inside of another method, etc.  You also have the other same-thread options I discussed; mutation from a called method, an event that fires, other types of delegates called, possibly through any number of layers of indirection (i.e. materializing something using deferred execution that mutates the array), etc.  Just too many things to check.

Comment: @user2864740 That's still going to be quite hard for the runtime to do; to know what locations in memory can confidently be accessed without having been changed.  Memory ends up being cached already by the cache, who's sole purpose is to make repeated access to memory very, very fast, while still maintaining data integrity.  There's no *reason* to do this, even if it could.

Comment: `TestWithIndex` and `TestWithTemp` are not the same IL in my example.

Comment: In my experience, there will be a performance difference (but a very small one that will only matter in really tight loops; I have had occasions where this kind of optimization made a difference, *but I only did this after profiling*).  I'm fairly certain the C# compiler will produce one ldelem for each access written in the code.  @Servy has adequately explained why, I think.

Comment: @KonradKokosa, the code would have to be compiled in `Release` with the optimizations enabled. Now keep in mind you never do benchmarking in `Debug`.

Comment: I do look at IL generated in Release with optimizations enabled and they are not the same.

Comment: @KonradKokosa, I guess I can't explain that then. I know that the two were different in `Debug` (as I suspected) and the same in `Release`.

Comment: I suspect that is because of context. In your `Main` compiler optimizes because there is no more code possible. But in case of methods, it cannot assume anything about arrays?

Comment: @KonradKokosa, I guess that's a reasonable possibility.

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have performance requirements or performance problems, then your main goal is to write readable code which will be easy to maintain. It's easy to see duplication in your first example:

```
int x = array[1] * 2;
int y = array[1] * 3;
int z = array[1] * 4;
```

It has several issues. First - the more you have duplicated code, the more code you have to support and the higher chance you will not modify one of code copies at some point of time. Second - duplication always means you have hidden knowledge in your code. If some code is repeated then it has specific meaning, which you haven't made obvious. E.g. you have speed value in second item of array. Make this knowledge explicit:

```
int speed = array[1];
int x = speed * 2; // of course, magic numbers also should be replaced
int y = speed * 3;
int z = speed * 4;
```

And remember - premature optimization is evil. Usually you have 20% of code which takes 80% of execution time. There is high probability that your optimizations will not affect application performance. So, you should find these 20% first, and only then do optimizations (if they really needed).